# Training to hold your breath for longer underwater

Tags: swimming, breathing

Is there any type of training you can do to help maintain your breath underwater?

When diving in a lake, using only diving goggles, I can hold my breath for about 10 seconds before needing to surface. Can I do anything to improve that time?

Comment: Googling for `how to train breath holding` brings up several entries. What have you tried?

Comment: I've held my breath in rounds before: hold 1 minute, rest, repeat. Ive not done this regularly. Sitting now, I can hold my breath for 1:30 but that doesn't correlate to underwater time.

Comment: Anecdotally, I was obsessed with this for some time after seeing one of those famous illusionists do it for a ridiculous amount of time. He was lowered into a tank of water and his feet were placed in shackles that held him under. But because the shackles were loose, he had to point his toes upward to stay submerged, and simply having to spend oxygen flexing *anything* will dramatically reduce your capacity to hold your breath. Point being, results and measurements will vary a lot, and as you accurately point out, whatever you do sitting won't translate well to underwater time.

Comment: Anyway, just to curve it on topic, improving your swimming technique will also dramatically increase the length you can swim while submerged, since you'll be spending less oxygen per unit distance.

Comment: I had not thought of that, @Alec. I'm definitely not a great swimmer so that could be important.

Comment: I want to write an answer to this, but I don't even know where to start, there's just so much information about it. Given your comments, and what I know from experience, I would guess that your main issue is relaxation. You say you're not a great swimmer, so if you go underwater thinking about breathing, you're going to want to breathe. First thing to check is how is your breathing? You need to breathe well, meaning diaphragmatic breathing (your shoulders shouldn't move). Second is just get comfortable with your face in the water holding your breath (static apnea).

Comment: If the water is on the cooler side, then your mammalian dive reflex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_reflex) will kick in, making it a bit easier.

Comment: Fun facts for you, current world record for static apnea is over 20 minutes with oxygen and over 10 minutes without. Honestly though, breathing is a massive, complex topic. If you really want to improve, I'd highly (seriously highly) recommend looking at freediving courses (which I currently happen to be doing).

Comment: Do you think this is a question that should be broken into pieces, @DarkHippo? I'm thinking I may have asked something too vague given my lack of knowledge on the subject.

Comment: @C.Lange I'm probably just overthinking it as it's something I'm very interested in. There might be a little confusion as to whether you mean swimming underwater or diving deeper, but I'm 90% confident you're actually asking about just swimming underwater. Actually, re-reading your question, is it purely following a dive that you're interested in staying underwater for longer (again horizontally or vertically)?

Comment: @DarkHippo -- usually I don't have an issue getting to the bottom of the lake (where I'm swimming in the shallow areas) but then I run out of breath looking around the lake bed. So, I would say I'm interested in swimming around underwater for longer (horizontally). My vertical technique could probably use some work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I need to tell you this: **Don't hyperventilate**. When one does that the percentage of CO2 reduces and CO2 is responsible to help you understand that you need to resurface. A friend of mine, really good diver, died last year probably due to that.

The training plans depend on your goals, but there are exercises for big wave surfers, for spearfishers,...  There are dry and wet trainings one can do:

- **Dry trains** include things like CO2/O2 tables. The first one helps one handle high levels of CO2 in the luns and the last one helps one store more O2.
- For **wet exercises**, I always recommend doing them with supervision. And one has activities like finding objects underwater, swimming distances underwater (with various intensities) ,...

When holding one's breath, one should keep in mind that every move, or even thought, consumes energy. So, keep calm. By being calm, one might also reduce the heartbeat rate, which is one of the tricks I use to hold the breath longer.

We, humans, have an advantage: [Mammalian Diving Reflex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_reflex).

> The diving reflex is triggered specifically by chilling and wetting the nostrils and face while breath-holding,

Finally, and sharing my personal experience, spearfishing with frequency, cardios (such as swimming, running) and some complementary gym training (weight lifting) is enough to help me hold the breath, statically, for more than 4min.